# Netbook without Windows?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, drivers, hardware-rec, netbook

I have been looking around for a netbook without Windows and with Ubuntu preinstalled. Almost all I have seen have Windows. The main issue is making sure that the computer ships with the right Ubuntu drivers and, hopefully, saving a little without having to pay for Windows. So far, I cannot find one.

Comment: You mean "ships with hardware that is compatible with Ubuntu", correct?

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off-topic as defined by the [FAQ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a Notebook with full Intel insides (or Intel insides and a NVidia card (ION)). That will be 100% compatible. Anyway, post a book what you find and I'll (or we) tell you whether its compatible totally or not. Usually Intel is always compatible (such as Nvidia) since they put a lot of effort into that.

Comment: Comment/extra info: In some country, you can get back the cost of the pre-installed Windows. You may want to ask about this in an IT store (in your country).

Comment: Also. If you buy a good laptop which supports Linux, you get a better deal. For example ThinkPad works 100% on Linux. HDPS, battery threshold, bla bla. Okay, ThinkPad is a notebook but I guess you understand what I mean. Google around if you get the same as what you would get with Windows (in functions..that is).

Answer (score 3):

Dell sells netbooks that ship with ubuntu.

Comment: Full Intel stuff. Ubuntu will run on any Intel hardware. (Okay, maybe on anything but on VIA. NEVER buy a VIA based pc/notebook or (one with) ATI VGA if you want to use Linux EVER)

Comment: If I go to http://www.dell.com/home/laptops then click 'compare' all the operating systems listed is Windows.

Comment: Oh, weird, there were multiple options on Dell's European website. It looks like the ubuntu netbooks are very hidden on the US site:

http://www.ubuntu.com/dell

Comment: Thanks for the link! Well to add insult to injury, Dell sells the laptops with Ubuntu and without Windows for more than the Windows only machines!!!

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu doesn't come preinstalled on many computers period, much less netbooks. Your best choice is to find something that runs Linpus, then blow that away and install Ubuntu in its place.

Comment: Linpus? lol....

Answer (score 2):

Dell used to ship some netbooks with Ubuntu pre-installed, but I'm not sure that still do.

For a good list of netbook compatibility for Ubuntu, see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks

Comment: +1 for the hardware support link - you beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

While at work one day a customer was telling me that if you decline the licence agreement that Windows presents you when you run the computer for the first time you are in fact entitled to a refund for the cost of the Windows licence from the manufacturer.

You could simply reject the licence and reformat it with Ubuntu.

I can't specify any sources though as it was word of mouth.

Comment: I also have heard this. I also read it in a news article. It took the guy a while but (I think it was Dell) refunded him the OEM cost of the license.